# How to draw music score by musicxml in iOS?

Tags: ios, musicxml

Now I'm using musicxml, how do I use it on iOS to plot the score? Not immediately musicxml.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://github.com/drumnkyle/music-notation-kit

Comment: can't understand its usage.